# ¿Cómo pasar una función con argumento que se ejecuta a través de command=func(a) sin que esta se ejecute automáticamente? python: pygame, tkinter, os

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, menu, os

Estoy haciendo un programa para desarrollo personal con tkinter y pygame que me permita reproducir las canciones ('.mp3') que tengo descargadas en una carpeta.

Mi objetivo es crear una interfaz que muestre un cuadro de texto en el que el usuario pueda ingresar la canción que desea y definir botones que he definido como <<tk.Button(root, command=func)>>.

Hasta ahora, he conseguido pausar la canción, continuarla, reproducirla desde el principio, seleccionar una nueva canción, seleccionar una canción random diferente a la actual, adelantar 10s, atrasar 10s, subir el volumen y bajar el volumen.
A continuación, he creado un menú que muestra las canciones que hay en la carpeta y quiero que al clickar en una de las opciones, se reproduzca la canción seleccionada.
El método que he escogido para realizar este proceso es el siguiente:

```
options = tk.Menu(root, title='Opciones') # Menú con opciones
root.config(menu=options)  # Añade el menú a la ventana

def func(a):
    global actual_song
    actual_song['text'] = a  # actual_song['text'] es un label con la canción que se está reproduciendo
    pygame.mixer.music.load(a)  # Prepara la canción
    pygame.mixer.music.play()   # Reproduce la canción

opcion = tk.Menu(options, tearoff=False)

for i in [file for file in os.listdir(r'C:\ruta\de\la\carpeta') if file.endswith(r".mp3")]:
    opcion.add_command(label=i, command=func(i))

options.add_cascade(label="Opciones", menu=opcion)
```

i --> recorre cada archivo '.mp3' en la carpeta
opcion.add_command(...) --> crea una opción con el nombre de i, que quiero que se ejecute solo cuando clickee.

Problema: al añadir el argumento 'i' en command=func( ) para que la función sepa qué canción reproducir, se ejecuta automáticamente la función func(a) cuando se inicia el programa y no cuando se clickea.

Conclusión: el añadir un paréntesis a func para pasar un argumento provoca que se ejecute automáticamente, por lo que, a no ser que haya algún método que desconozco, command=func por narices.
Siguiente problema: si no paso ningún argumento, ¿cómo hago para reconocer la opción seleccionada?

Finalmente, si queréis que os proporcione más información sobre el código o no acabáis de entender la pregunta, sentiros libre de preguntar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), que te permite crear una función cuyos argumentos ya están fijados.

El código quedaría:

```py
for i in file_list:
    new_command = functools.partial(func, i)
    opcion.add_command(label=i, command=new_command)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge Luis por la rapidez y sencillez de tu respuesta. ¡¡Solucionado!!